# Can we make posts just as parts of a puzzle?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I want to spread a puzzle into several small parts and want to limit the puzzle to just interactions inside puzzling.SE. For example, players have to use SE's search bar with clues in the main puzzle to search for the spread out posts.

Can I make some posts that only hold small pieces of information for a puzzle but aren't puzzles themselves?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Every "post" should be a question that can be answered: either a question *about* puzzles, or a puzzle itself. If your post is just a bit of information useful for something else, it cannot be answered, and so it will likely be closed and deleted.